# When used Keys as a attached property of qml item, but Keys.onReleased was executed when there was no key released event!how solve it?

Tags: qt, qml, key, qt5

When using `Keys` as a attached property of `qml`, but `Keys.onReleased` was executed when there was no key `released` event! how solve it?

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    property string imagePath
    property string btnText
    property string btnColor: "white"
    property double btnWidth: 0
    property double btnHeight: 0
    property double btnRadius: 0
    property double btnTextSize: 0
    property double btnOpcity: 0.9
    property bool btnEnable: true
    property int spaceKeyEventTimes:0

    id: umButton
    width: 100
    height: 100


    Rectangle{
        id: umButton_Rec
        width: btnWidth
        height: btnHeight
        color: btnColor
        radius: btnRadius
        opacity: btnOpcity
        focus: true


        Text{
            //focus: true
            style: Text.Raised
            text:  btnText

            font.pixelSize: 29
        }
    }

    //////////////Handle KeyEvent from the system//////////////////

    Keys.enabled: true;


    Keys.onPressed: {
        switch(event.key)
        {
            case Qt.Key_Space:   
                console.log( "emit  btnPressed()" )               
                event.accepted = true
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Keys.onReleased: {
        switch(event.key)
        {
            case Qt.Key_Space://Qt.Key_Space
                console.log("emit  btnReleased()")              
                event.accepted = true

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is output? How did you test the issue?

Comment: Just pressed and held the Space key and the Keys.onPressed was executed.

Comment: Ok, but what reaction did you expect? If you _press_ a button it is expected that _onPressed_ fired.

Comment: yes, when press a button, it's ok that onPress() fired, but the onReleased() was also fired. I expect that the onReleased() is fired after I release the button, because I will use these two slots differently.

Comment: Ah, yes `onReleased` should not be fired if the button is still pressed. Maybe some contact bounce?

Comment: There was o contact bounce. I want to check the source code of Class Keys, but i don't know where can get the code.

Comment: I've tried many times. I think there is no contact bounce. I plan to check the source code of class Keys, but I have no idea of where to find the source code yet.

Comment: See [QQuickItem](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/5.11/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp#L815) sources.